# PyCharm + Django ImportError: cannot import newly created classes from models in python console

Tags: python, django, django-models, pycharm

I'm building Django website (Django 1.11.2  and Python 3.5.2), and I faced with the problem

```
File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'Test'
```

When executing a command `from events.models import Test`

Code of events.models

```
# coding=utf-8
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from http.client import HTTPSConnection
from datetime import timedelta
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
import json
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils.timezone import now

from django_cron import CronJobBase, Schedule

from django.db.models import Max


class EventClass(models.Model):
    game_class = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    game_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    tournament_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tournament_round = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tournament_type = models.CharField(max_length=100)



class Event(models.Model):

    game_class = models.CharField(max_length=100)

........................................
........................................

class Test(models.Model):
    test = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

How can I import without any error?

P.S.

```
from events.models import Event
```

works correctly

even tried

```
class EventClass2(models.Model):
    game_class = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    game_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    tournament_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tournament_round = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tournament_type = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Than

```
makemigration events
migrate events

from events.models import EventClass2
```

and again the same error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'EventClass2'
```

Comment: What is the whole path or your events.models in your project?Import Test using absolute path.

Comment: As @AnkitaGupta asked, will need to see the full `events.models` file because it sounds to me like one of your other models is attempting to make use of `Test` before it gets created but I'm not sure.

Comment: No actually test is just test class that I create, now I can't import any newly created class, and I don't know why.

Comment: Restarting PyCharm helped, don't know why ((